# ng-repeat get length of array and bind last value of array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-maxlength

```
$scope.GetDetails={
  Student:[
      {"id":1,"Name":"Apple","Price":3500}
    ],
  Student:[
      {"id":2,"Name":"Samsung","Price":4000}
     ],
  Student:[
    {"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price":1500},
    {"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price";7000}
   ]
 }
```

Am binding data using ng-repeat

```
 <div ng-repeat="As in GetDetails">
         <div ng-repeat="A in As.Student">
        <span>{{A.Name}}</span> - <span>{{A.Price}}</span>  
    </div>
     </div>
```

Result is 
    Apple - 3500
Samsung - 4000
Nokia - 1500
Nokia - 7000

Here every thing Ok.But what i want mean , Nokia have two array ,so i have to get name from first array and price from 2nd array Like,

Nokia - 7000,

And Also i need the length of student array.

Comment: you have to change the json format, the code you have given will not work with your HTML

Answer (score 1):

First, You should change your **`JSON`** to achieve your result.

Change JSON to below:

```
$scope.GetDetails=[
    {Student:[{"id":1,"Name":"Apple","Price":3500}]},
    {Student:[{"id":2,"Name":"Samsung","Price":4000}]},
    {Student:[{"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price":1500},{"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price":7000}]}
 ]
```

**Please run below code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <div ng-repeat="As in GetDetails">
         <div ng-repeat="A in As.Student" ng-if="$last">
        <span>{{A.Name}}</span> - <span>{{A.Price}}</span>  
    </div>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.GetDetails=[
    {Student:[{"id":1,"Name":"Apple","Price":3500}]},
    {Student:[{"id":2,"Name":"Samsung","Price":4000}]},
    {Student:[{"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price":1500},{"id":3,"Name":"Nokia","Price":7000}]}
 ]

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I used **`ng-if="$last"`** to take the last value from array

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LSg6fkOK4exuoT2FDdQq?p=preview)

Comment: @Vediyappan.V, checked it?

Comment: Thanks for  Reply its working well..I have one more doubt , How can find length of array. Ex student - Apple - Length 1,student - Samsung- Length 1,student - Nokia- Length 2. Just i need t bind length on ng-repeat.

Comment: @Vediyappan.V, you can use `{{GetDetails.length}}`, check the https://plnkr.co/edit/LSg6fkOK4exuoT2FDdQq?p=preview

Comment: @Vediyappan.V, anything else needed in this answer?

Comment: Thanks agian.J have one more doubt . While using JQuery library it cannot support all the function. EX.    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> Its for calender control and <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> this other .I Want use both . Have any solution for this.

Comment: did not get you. could you elaborate?

Comment: you want to use two jquery versions?

Comment: Yes i want use two jQuery verision

Comment: [check this link, this might be useful](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/). But I dont prefer using both the versions. Use the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this only for `Name: Nokia`, then do it like;

```
<div ng-repeat="A in As.Student">
 <span ng-if="A.Name!=='Nokia'">{{A.Name}}-{{A.Price}}</span>  
 <span ng-if="A.Name==='Nokia' && $last">{{A.Name}}-{{A.Price}}</span>  
</div>
```

and it you want  only `last element` from every array :

then:

```
 <div ng-repeat="A in As.Student" ng-if="$last">
        <span>{{A.Name}}</span> - <span>{{A.Price}}</span>  
 </div>
```